# My Raspberry Pi will not open the pi directory

Tags: raspbian-buster

Whenever I try to change the directory to pi, using the command `$ cd ~`, it displays the error:

```
bash:  $:  command not found
```

Why is this not working?

Answer (score 4):

The command you need to enter is `cd ~`

The `$` is just a common prompt from the shell that it is awaiting a command, it is not meant to be typed as part of the command.

Comment: The `~` is superfluous

Comment: It is usually superfluous when used with cd.  I'm not going to say it's always superfluous though as that depends on whether it's a built-in and the shell being used and which environment variables are set.